# Temporary tablespace always full

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I've been having this problem, just need more information about error below

-1652-ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace "temp_tablespace name"
i need to increase the temp tablespace almost every month now.

currently at midnight everyday, the system running stored procedure to insert data collected from 2-3 tables into 1 table. in the query, i use "distinct" statement to query. i need to use distinct because before this, there's duplicate value inserted eventhough the table have primary keys.

My question is:

1) does "distinct" syntax caused the temp tablespace to be full?

2) if yes, then what i need to do so instead increasing the tablespace? if no, then what cause the temp tablespace always full?

Comment: using distinct in query means - first select all the data in the temp location and filter the distinct, this will use your temporary database space. - what is your process doing by selecting this data?

Comment: the process? do you mean what happen to the data after selecting it? if so, the data will be inserted into another table so that the system will extract it into a batch file.

Comment: That's wonderful! if you want to insert the records in another table, you can work with batch of data from the total number of records. First select the count and then proceed with insert activity batch by batch. this will reduce temporary space.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary tablespaces should appear "full" after a while in a normally running database.
Extents are allocated once and then managed by the system.  Rather then doing the rather 
expensive operation of "space management" (data dictionary updates), the system will 
allocate an extent in TEMP and then keep it and manage it itself.  This is normal and 
to be expected and is not an indication that you do not have any temporary space.

See the dynamic performance views V$SORT_USAGE and V$SORT_SEGMENT for more information 
regarding the usage of space within these temporary segments.  V$SORT_USAGE will tell you 
who's using what.